# Software Design: How to model an entity that can go to the internet and also have the data cached?

Tags: design-patterns

Let's do it with an example. Let's consider a Company entity that has a functionality to retrieve the employees - `getEmployees()`. A company may have lots of employees so the employees are not loaded when the Company is loaded. But, once the employees were loaded, they are saved in the cache and will be retrieved immediately upon next invocation.

Now I would like to present the list of employees in a list view - GUI.

I would like to provide a 'loading' indication, while the employees are loaded from the internet.

But, when loaded from the cache (very fast) it would be an annoyance to present the 'loading' indicator and drop it immediately. **So, when already loaded, I would NOT want to show the 'loading' indicator at all.**

How would you tackle this design question? Would you add a method `getCachedEmployees()`? Perhaps `isEmployeesCached()`? Perhaps change the method to `getEmployees(boolean cache)`?

I don't like any of the above because instead of encapsulating the cache, the cache is emphasized  - thus complicating the software.

**Any other ideas?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you have your GUI and code for displaying and managing your GUI elements decoupled from your application logic and data.

I understand that if some action in the GUI triggers the application logic to load the employees, you just want to invoke the getEmployees() method. Your GUI should not control if data is loaded from the cache or internet. But you need a logic in the GUI to decide  if the loading indication needs to be displayed.

The best solution I can think of would be that your GUI has something like a timer - you invoke the getEmployees() method, wait for 500ms and if data was already returned you display them directly. If not data was returned so far you need to display the loading indicator. You will need an asynchrous call and callback here, so you probably want to have something like a separate class doing the synchronization here, but it probably will be worth the efford.

I have implented something similar in .NET/C#, where an action is triggered only after 500ms of wait time if special other conditions are also true. When using the application the user will recognize a little bit delay in the reaction of the GUI, but it won't disturb your overall look & feel.

By the way, I like the approach to have only one getEmployees() method shown to your GUI. This way you make sure that you have a strict separation between GUI and application logic...

Comment: Nice idea. During the 500ms, should the UI stay responsive?

Comment: Depends - I would say yes, even if this means a little bit more efford in the implementation. 500ms would be short enough that the user would not necessarily notice if the application is frozen, but sure it would be a cleaner implementation if the application stays responsive. And if you see that you need to extend the wait time to 1 sec for some reason, then you will sure have to keep the UI alive.

Comment: Keeping the ui alive would mean that the user might click on other stuff while the app processes the first click. Bad experience.

Comment: That's right. Your sure need to disable some triggers. In our last application when we where loading large amount of data over the network, some buttons always were grayed out right after clicking. If the data was loaded fast (within 2 seconds) the result was displayed immediately, if it took some more time a rotating circle as a loading indicator was displayed.

Comment: I'm not comfortable with disabling the UI entirely nor with extra coding for disabling specific buttons.

Comment: Also, what if the data is returned 600ms after the request? After 500ms, the loading indicator would pop up for just 100ms - that's exactly what we wanted to prevent.

Comment: I feel that the solution would be to design something else, like if a button is clicked, go to a different page and show that the data is loaded in a very non-intrusive small indicator. Example: a spinning icon at the top of the table header holding the loaded data. With this approach, it doesn't really matter if the content is loaded immediately or not.

Comment: I had some problem with my logic regarding the 600ms theory. Showing the indicator for 100ms is practically identical to showing it for 600ms. The solution doesn't make the problem worse - it just doesn't solve that scenario.

Comment: Hm... does that mean that if the data is cached it is not displayed within 600ms ? So even if you access the cached data you need longer time to display it in the GUI?

Comment: Not necessary. It means that if retrieving the information from the inet is fast (600ms), we still have a UI annoyance.